# Upgrading my APP to support API Level 19

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android APP in Google Play which I have created and Launched when we had API 18. Now API 19 has come, I just need to make my APP to be visible for all devices which has the latest OS versions.

Kindly let me know what are all changes I need to make in the existing package.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you need to change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specified maxSdkVersion (which would be weird) your app will be visible for all API 19 users.

So, the answer is: no change needed

Comment: I have used the following xml. Will there be any change in targetSdkVersion parameter                                                                            
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" /> 
  
or the project properties  which has the statement 'target=android-18'

Comment: You could of course just read the documentation.  As Waza_Be says, you only need to change anything if you have used maxSdkVersion.

Comment: You can imagine the nightmare that Google would create if all apps in the Play Store needed to be updated ;-)